# Is it possible to remove pagecreate event?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a pagecreate declaration in my page. It is created each time I read a json file for each value in it.

The problem is that if I read the json file 3 times (with a refreshing button), pagecreate is declared 3 times for each value. So I get same declarations many times.

Is it possible to delete a "pagecreate" declaration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you use **[on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** to create the handler and **[off()](https://api.jquery.com/off/)** to remove the handler.

```
$(document).on("pagecreate","#page1", function(){ 

});

$(document).off("pagecreate","#page1");
```

Comment: Thanks. I think you have a little mistake but I am not sure. I have to change your second line to: $("#page1").off("pagecreate"); to make it works. But thanks to you I discovered that method.